# Using C++ modules in VS 2015 inside VS IDE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am following tutorial on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/#comment-111821

I have a requirement to use this newly introduced module feature inside VS 2015.
Where I have cpp and .h files in my VS project. But my VS project is not a typical C++ project. So Intellisense is not working. So with this new feature is there a possibility to get Intellisense support inside VS for cpp files those are not in a cpp project. (I was thinking about importing .h files with this feature as modules and get available methods of them in Intellisense menu).

Comment: Are you aware that this is an experimental feature that is not yet fully developed? You are probably expecting too much at this stage.

Comment: Intellisense is implemented by a different compiler (Really! Don't ask :-) which doesn't have the same experimental features implemented.